# Illustration of how memory addresses are used by the CPU

Tags: caching, memory, x86, cpu

Given: all the bytes to read are present in the nearest CPU cache(i.e as immediately available as possible); the architecture is x86; it is only relevant when I use the z/y../X bits/bytes notation how exactly the bits/bytes of the architecture are used(e.g. x86-64 vs 32 bit architecture variations).

The CPU requests a byte from the cache by addressing it with its block TAG naturally followed(or preceded) by the block offset(to access an individual byte using the combined KEY from sent to the cache assuming the cache block queried is available and not cold). Does the CPU load the byte pointed and the following 3/7.../X bytes(depending on architecture) after it? Assuming it does, and assuming its the minimum the CPU can read from memory at a time, lets call this the MINIMUM AMOUNT OF READABLE MEMORY BYTES(please correct me if im wrong on the exact term). Thus I ask: must the block offset be a maximum of (BLOCK SIZE - 1 - MINIMUM AMOUNT OF READABLE MEMORY BYTES)? I also ask: Can the CPU start reading from a block offset address that isnt a multiple of MINIMUM AMOUNT OF READABLE MEMORY BYTES?

To anwer the questions below first answer what is above. Consider specially the following question: "Does the CPU load the byte pointed and the following 3/7.../X bytes(depending on architecture) after it?".

If my conjecture is not accurate, does it mean the CPU can read any individual byte by itself and just copy its contents into the low-bits of a 32/64.../X bit register(or are the bits placed in a larger register some other way?)? Are there any smaller registers for this purpose?

Comment: Is this question valid if it is asked in this website or should I ask it in another stack exchange website? please let me know because the downvotes make me sad if I dont get an explanation as to how not to get them!

Comment: Please [don't take it personally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin), it's how the system is supposed to work. I do think the question fits though, I just think it is a bit hard to read. Maybe you can work on the formatting, add some clearer example what you mean and split it in a few more paragraphs. I am not entirely sure what the question exactly _is_ that you are asking, even after reading it twice, so that may be the reason for some downvotes too.

Comment: it boils down to first answering this: "Does the CPU load the byte pointed and the following 3/7.../X bytes(depending on architecture) after it?" and then evaluating the rest of the question.

Comment: @CherryDT I understand, I am however simply requesting guidance, not forcing anyone to give me some.

Answer (score 3):

You have a processor that asks for and executes instructions of which some are external read/writes (load/stores).  The processor has one or more buses around it to do this.  A cache implementation is not necessarily the processors job at this layer.

A cache is normally inline with a processor bus such that the cache can handle the request or pass it on or do a cache line fetch or eviction, etc.  The width and depth of the sram(s) in the cache, and as a result tags and such that are part of that cache design, and naturally would need to be designed to match the rest of the system.  but the processor doesn't need to care, it puts the fetch or read or write out there, based on design it may indicate cacheability or more likely it is the mmu which is between the processor and the cache and the user uses the mmu to indicate cacheablity as well as virtual addresses and such.   the cache design uses the tag/status to determine if there is a hit or miss, then the design determines what to do next.  What the size of the cache line is which determines the request on the bus on the far side of the cache.  As needed if there is a miss but no room in that way then an eviction needs to happen and what gets evicted is based on the design and sometimes programmability of the cache.

So if it is a write of a byte for example then the tag determines what line it is in and if that line is there or not.  then it would fetch the line as needed (following an eviction if needed), then once fetched a read-modify write of the addressable item within the sram to place that byte, a dirty flag would be set and so on.

If it is a read then if a miss then a cache line read needs to happen after an eviction as needed, then once the line is there related to that address, the number of cache sram reads needed to fill the bus per the rules of the bus are read and put on the bus and returned to the processor, the processor then extracts the bits per the instruction and sign extends or pads or not as determined by the instruction.

So if you had a 128 bit cache line in an L1 cache, with a 32 bit wide cpu bus and a 32 bit wide sram within the cache and wanted to do an 8 bit read then eventually the 32 bits containing that byte in the cache sram would be read and put on the bus for the cpu which would then extract the byte from the bus.  This is not-atypical but naturally any processor/chip can be designed however and can under or overcomplicate this as desired.

For the write same deal except that the bus would indicate the byte lane and the sram item would be read, the byte modified, and written back along with indicating that line is dirty.

Now I maybe meant flush instead of evict, hopefully you understand.  If the cache line has been modified since read then it needs to be written out if it needs to leave to make room for another cache line.  If it has not been modified then it can be discarded and doesn't need to be written back out the far side.

The processor can do what the processor can do and it does what the programmer asked, processors are very dumb.  If a user requests the processor can start reading blocks of data in whatever size from whatever address, and the cache simply responds, so if the processor is reading a string one byte at a time, then worst case per cache line there is a very long delay while a line is freed up and fetched/filled and then the one byte comes out of it but that is in part the idea of caches, because the hope is that that line gets used on recently following accesses so then the next so many reads of a byte will result in hits and return very quickly back to the processor.  if the loop goes long enough it may fall over into another cache line cause another cache line read and then the next so many are very fast.

Same with instructions, ideally code is linear so you get more than one fetch per cache line read and not have a lot of jumping that can if you try have the cache make your performance worse rather than better.

The cpu requests and address, the mmu, the layers of caches and the slow dram on the far end might all get affected.  the instruction specification/design dictates the size of the transfer that goes out from the processor and is cached or not.  And each layer simply does its job.

Some processor/system designs are such that you must do an aligned transfer, x86 for various reasons does not impose this, but mips/arm do/did.  x86 has evolved to contain a lot of overhead, where mips and arm are higher performance. Its line a mile long train with a lot of boxes in it vs a line of sports cars with one box each.  Forced alignment is part of that performance.  x86 permits the various sized operations on any (byte based) address.  arm these days does as well but you can suffer the performance hit (its like the train hitting a small animal vs the sports car) so it is undesirable.  And the alignment enforcement is usually programmable a bit you can set to allow it or not.

So the minimum number of bytes on most processors is 8, beyond that it depends on the instruction set 16? 32? 64? 128?  and so on.  And that doesn't mean that because you are doing a 128 bit write that that means a single transfer on the bus is going to handle it.  If you have a 64 bit bus and you do a 128 bit transfer aligned on a 32 bit boundary say 0x10004 but not on a 64 bit boundary that may turn into three transfers depending on the processor/bus a 32 bit at 0x10004, a 64 bit at 0x10010 and a 32 bit at 0x10014.  Or it may do a 128 bit transfer (8 bytes) at the unaligned 0x10004 address and the cache or peripheral on the other side of the bus has to deal with it.

x86 of course has the situation where you have one register which can be accessed in parts al,ah,ax,eax,rax and as a result what the single byte from the bus does depends for that processor on the instruction, and the documentation/design of that instruction indicates what happens (mov al, byte ptr [rbx] only affecting 8 bits of rax).  This is not typical either the instruction set directly or the user has to add more code to deal with handling of registers so if you want to only change one byte in a register depending on the instruction set it is not uncommon to need to use a second register to do the read then possibly a third register to mask the destination register (and the second register as needed) if needed shift the second register and then orr the bits into the destination register.

```
ldrb r1,[r3]
ldr r2,=0xFFFF00FF
and r0,r0,r2
lsl r1,r1,#8
orr r0,r0,r1
```

Now there are folks that are going to tell you that there are performance hits in using the smaller al,ah etc, depending on the chip and microcoding (x86 is microcoded as with many CISCs), so while the risc appears horrible that doesn't mean that the cisc isn't internally.

it is somewhat typical that a processor with more than 8 bits in a general purpose register has a load byte instruction, and that byte will be read and go into the lower bytes of the register and usually the upper bits are either zeroed or sign extended depending on the instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody is answering my question, this other question in the software engineering stack exchange site has an asnwer that answers it perfectly(the most voted one titled: **"Because the width of the data bus and the size of the smallest addressable unit are two separate things."**)!

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363370/how-does-a-cpu-load-multiple-bytes-at-once-if-memory-is-byte-addressed

Comment: I still think that this question in this site is relevant so as to provide an alternative reasoning as to how to reach the same question.(correct me if I should delete it)